# Passing product info to Shopping Cart using Sessions - PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm hoping someone can help me out. I'm not understanding how to pass product information using a Session from my products page to my shopping cart page. I've seen plenty of tutorials showing how to use it within the same page, but nothing understandable passing it from page to page. Thanks for the help!

Here is my products page with data file connection.

```
        <?php

        session_start();

        $data = file('products.dat');


        foreach ($data as $line) {

            $products = explode(",", $line);
            $id = $products[0];
            $product = $products[1];
            $description = $products[2];
            $price = $products[3];                
            $image = $products[4];

            $_SESSION['cart'] = array($id, $product, $price);

        ?>
            <div class="product">
                <?php print "<image class=\"product_image\" src=\"img/$image\">" ?><br>
                <?php print $id; ?><br>
                <?php print $title; ?><br>
                <?php print $description; ?><br>
                <?php print $price; ?>
                <form method="get" action="viewcart.php?action=addcart">
                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php print $product?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php print $price?>" />
                    <button type="submit">Add To Cart</button>
                </div> <br>
                </form>

            </div>
        <?php }; ?>
```

And my cart page.

```
<?php

    session_start();

?>

           <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="left">Product</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left"><?php print $_SESSION['cart'][1]; ?></td>
                <td class="center">1</td>
                <td class="center"><?php print $_SESSION['cart'][2]; ?></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

EDIT: I've thrown a `session_start()` on each page and edited my products page to have a `$_SESSION['cart']` in my initial foreach loop that when tested it will print out the proper information for each item. The new problem is that when I add something to my cart the `GET` send the correct info over the URL but only will display the last item in the products array. Any advice here?

Comment: As a brief overview, `$_SESSION['cart']` could contain an array of cart items, each item should have a product id, quantity, and potentially the price the customer saw it at the time of committing it to the cart, or a reference to the pricing id at that point in time. `session_start()` should exist on any page you need to use `$_SESSION`.

Comment: when you go to load the cart page, you would use the product ID's and quantities from `$_SESSION['cart']` to align with what to show from your database.

Comment: Thanks @Scuzzy. I've updated my code and am running into a new issue where it's only displaying the last item in the products array. I've updated my code above to show what I did.

Comment: it's because you're taking your products database, and for each loop you're trying to set `$_SESSION['cart'] = array($id, $product, $price);` which means whatever one is done last, is set. I don't see your "add to cart" logic, all you're doing is reading file('products.dat') into $_SESSION['cart']

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `session_start()` function on every page. Without it nothing will work.

Comment: Is it a new question ? You can ask it there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask